# QML catch all key events

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am not sure I understand why the notion of **focus** is meaningful for QML and mobile devices having touch interfaces... this may be related to my problem below.

I have defined a **CustomItem** that inherits **QQuickItem**. I have implemented event handlers for key press and release:

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
```

1. These event handlers are actually never called and I suspect that it comes from my CustomItem never having the focus. Anyone can confirm?
2. Now it turns I would rather have a top level object received and handling all these key events. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, have you set focus to true?

Comment: you could instal an event filter on the application object

Comment: Haha interesting, i'll test these.

Comment: What I do is set focus manually to a single object, which is used as an event dispatcher. It is much faster to do in QML, since you can prototype and test right away without waiting on slow compilations. And you can forward events to multiple objects.

Comment: @dtech: so your event dispatcher does not even have to have a visual associated to it, is that right? And you have it dispatch the events to say a C++ Controller class, is that correct?

Comment: Well, non-visual items can't have focus in QML, but a stock `Item`, while still technically "visual" has no visual representation, so practically it is not visible. And from there you can do with the events as you will.